# Safest way to format and add unassigned partition to Ubuntu partition in a dual boot system with win 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, format, format-conversion

What is the safest way to format and add unassigned partition in a dual boot system with windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04.02. I usually tweak with my Ubuntu os and sometimes because of problematic tweaking my whole system will crash and I have to reinstall the OS once more. I reinstalled ubutntu in my dual boot system using live usb and I am able to successfully re install ubuntu without any visible problem. During my first installation of Ubuntu on my system I have assigned near 15GB of space only for Ubuntu os but now i only have 9.3 GB.

[image]

The image above shows the different partition in my system where `sda1-6` is for windows and other drives. `sda8` (9.3GB) is current Ubuntu partition `sda7` and `sda9` (2.9GB)are unassigned partitions. I want to know how to add sda7 and sda9 to sda8 thus becoming 15 GB single partition safely with out causing any boot or OS problem.

Comment: I think you should use gparted from live cd and move sda8 to beginning of sda7 and then resize it to include all the partitions (2.9+2.9 gb) to its right.

Comment: @Ron Did that mean i have to reinstall ubuntu again?

Comment: no, you don't have to.

Comment: @ron it would be very help ful if you can give some steps  regarding that. I have never used gparted and partitioning is a riskier task

Comment: There are numerous [resources](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions) available in the internet. Try reading through [official](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition) guide to start with.

Comment: @Ron is it wise to run gparted from the mounted ubuntu  system instead of  live usb?

Comment: It is advised not to. While in the live USB, make sure the partitions are unmounted.

Comment: @ron how to mount  `sda7` and `sda9` in a live usb.? other drives i can mount by opening the concerned drives

Comment: Can't you see those drives when you open 'gparted` from live USB?

Comment: @Ron yeah i can see those drives sda7/9 its file system is `unknown` what should i do should I delete those partition or format it as ext or fat32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of ron i have found solution to the unassigned partition problem. This is how I solved it

1. Made a live persistent USB disk of ubuntu
2. Opened Gparted from dash in live USB
3. gparted showed `sda7` and `sda9` file system as `unknown`
4. Deleted `sda7` and `sda9` and automatically those space were assigned as 
   `unallocated`
5. Selected ubuntu partition ie `sda8` and chose option resize/move and used unallocated space to expand size
6. As expected boot loading problem arised (grub corrupted)
7. To solve grub problem,Installed [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in live usb
8. Used `recommended repair` settings from boot-repair
9. Restarted the OS